# For which values of a does $\int\int_Dr^{-a}\,dA$ converge where $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and D in the unit disk $1≥x^2+y^2$?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Recall that the improper integral $\int_0^1x^{-a}\,dx$ converged on if a<1. For which values of a does $\int\int_Dr^{-a}\,dA$ converge where $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and D in the unit disk $1≥x^2+y^2$?

Comment: What have *you* tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do polar coordinates:

$$\iint_D r^{-a}\,dA=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1 r^{-a}\cdot r\,dr\,d\theta=2\pi\int_0^1r^{-a+1}dr=\begin{cases}\left.\cfrac{r^{-a+2}}{-a+2}\right|_0^1=\cfrac1{2-a}\;,&a\neq2\\{}\\\left.\log r\right|_0^1 =\ldots,&a=2\end{cases}$$

End the argument.